# Where did 47gigabytes of space go?

Tags: linux, debian, samba, raid

Clean installation od Debian squeeze 6.0.6 x64 on intel atom 230, with 3 HDDs, with 3x500GB.

`df -h` shows :

```
datastore              size used  free   %   mounted
/dev/md0              917G  909M  870G   1% /
tmpfs                1001M     0 1001M   0% /lib/init/rw
udev                  996M  188K  996M   1% /dev
tmpfs                1001M     0 1001M   0% /dev/shm
```

`df -i` shows :

```
datastore              size used  free   %   mounted
/dev/md0             61054976   27582 61027394    1% /
tmpfs                 256087       7  256080    1% /lib/init/rw
udev                  254831     692  254139    1% /dev
tmpfs                 256087       1  256086    1% /dev/shm
```

It is ext3.

Please tell me, where did my 47 gigabytes go?
It is a clean installation as you can see.

`du -sh` shows:
709M

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Does this help?

```
man mkfs.ext3
-m reserved-blocks-percentage
   Specify the percentage of the filesystem blocks reserved for the
   super-user.   This  avoids  fragmentation, and allows root-owned
   daemons, such as syslogd(8), to continue to  function  correctly
   after non-privileged processes are prevented from writing to the
   filesystem.  The default percentage is 5%.
```

Comment: So you say, everything is OK? Well, 5% is about 45 or 47Gigabytes. Is it possible to change from 5 to 3%?

Comment: All works as defined, yes. :)  To reduce the reserved blocks:   tune2fs -m reserved-blocks-percentage /dev/md0

Answer (score 1):

47G from 917G is close to 5%.
This is the default amount of reserved blocks used for super-user aims. You can see that executing `tune2fs -l /dev/md0 | grep "Reserved block count"`. `-m` parameter of `tune2fs` and `mke2fs` can change the default behavior.

Comment: _Don't_ dare touch that! That is breathing space, if the filesystem ever gets too full it will slow down to a crawl. Besides, root has a special dispensation and can use (some) oe the reserved space.